# Определить угол между векторами

Tags: c++

Заданы два вектора `x{x1,x2,...,x10}, y{y1,y2,...,y10}`. Определить угол между векторами `x` и `y` по формуле

[image: \phi =arccos\left (\frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{(x,x)(y,y)}} \right )]

Comment: Можете привести код, что у вас получилось?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос без ошибок. Не бывает функции `arccos` с двумя аргументами, тем более если эти аргументы десятимерные векторы.

Comment: исправленный вариант

Comment: Где исправленный вариант?

Comment: формула вообще выглядит как f = arccos(x,y)/(sqrt(x,x) * sqrt(y,y))

Comment: А в чём ваше затруднение? Какая из операций представляет проблему? Скалярное произведение, корень или арккосинус?

Comment: См. на английском: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066933/direct-way-of-computing-clockwise-angle-between-2-vectors

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов, круглыми скобками может обозначаться скалярное произведение. Так что формула вроде правдоподобная.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

В математике при работе с векторами часто встречается запись вида `(x,y)`, где `x` и `y` - векторы. Обычно данная запись обозначает *скалярное произведение* векторов. В N-мерном евклидовом пространстве скалярное произведение определяется формулой

```
(x,y) = x_1*y_1+... +x_N*y_N, 
где x=(x_1,...,x_N), y=(y_1,...,y_N),
    x_1,...,x_N,y_1,...,y_N - вещественные числа.
```

Функцию вычисления евклидова скалярного произведения можно записать следующим образом:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> T scalarProduct(const T *const x, 
                                     const T *const y, 
                                     const size_t dimension)
{
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, 
                  "Template type MUST be arithmetic!");

    T result = 0;
    for (size_t index = 0; index < dimension; ++index)
        result += x[index] * y[index];
    return result;
}
```

С использованием этой функции и стандартной библиотеки теперь можно вычислить требуемый угол между векторами:

```
#include <cmath>

const double x[] = { /* вставить числа */ };
const double y[] = { /* вставить числа */ };
constexpr size_t N = sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);  // Размерность пространства.

static_assert(sizeof(y) / sizeof(y[0]) == N, 
              "Vectors have different dimensions!");

double phi = acos(scalarProduct(x, y, N) / sqrt(scalarProduct(x, x, N) * scalarProduct(y, y, N)));
```

**Примечание.** Требуется компилятор с поддержкой стандарта `c++11`.

Comment: @Abyx Спасибо! Не знал... P.S. Чёрт! Надо почитать поподробнее про STL...